# Android - Building error after enable firebase cloud in project structure

Tags: java, android, firebase

My Project build successfully before i checked `Firebase Cloud` in `Android Studio`'s Project Structure. The Error i get after enable it :

```
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':processFlavorDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/me212/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have unchecked the `firebase cloud`, but it not resolved.

Below are my `Build.Gradle`, i have Up/Down Grade the buildTools version but still no luck  :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.3.0'
    compile project(':baseGameUtils')
    compile project(':andEngine')
    compile project(':andEngineTMXTiledMapExtension')
    compile project(':andEngineDebugDrawExtension')
    compile project(':unity-ads')

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
}

//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23"

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavor {
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
            applicationId 'com.myapps'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId 'com.myappsDebug'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src', 'src/main/resources', 'src/main/resources/jniLibs']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: @Yvette i downgrade about 5 minutes ago as suggestion from AugustoCarmo

Comment: @Yvette i have added build.grade in description

Comment: @Yvette my target SDK is 21 and i have downgrade it to 21, but build still error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1` (Use this version if you're supporting Android N) but your `compileSdkVersion` is 21 which is wrong. If you want to use latest version of support library, you also need to increase your target sdk version. Try change `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 24.

For your information, android sdk 24 is for Android N (Nougat). If you're not targeting this android version, please downgrade your support library to `com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0` and change `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 23.

Comment: @user2226388 the first number of the version is reflected to the number of sdk. For example; 24.1.1, the first number is 24, that is the sdk version that you need to use.

Answer (score 1):

Match your build tool version to your sdk

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

buildToolsVersion "23"

targetSdkVersion 21
```

So change to:

```
buildToolsVersion "23"
```

Also, don't downgrade the target sdk to match the tools, upgrade the tools to match the target sdk.